# Create Clean Rounded Corners on UITextField within UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm creating a UITextField within a UITableViewCell with rounded corners

```
UITextField *someTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 9, 135, 20)];

someTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
someTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

Is there a way to make the corner area, the part between the rounded corner and the square corner clear so that the background color doesn't show there.
Any help is appreciated.
lq

[NOTE: I answered my own question. Sorry, it was a lame one. lq]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Doh! This gets rid of the white corners:
someTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```